# Iconos a color en navigation drawer?

Tags: android, navigationview

Como puedo poner iconos a color en el navigation drawer como por ejemplo las apps de Google que toman sus colores; he intentado pero al poner un icono personalizado este se pone gris y no toma el color original, probé declarando el atributo en el navigationview (setIconItemTintList) pero se ponen todos del mismo color y yo quiero es que cada uno tome su color propio

Comment: poniendo el método que dices siempre me funciona, quizás por ahi en tu layout le estás poniendo color a los iconos.

setIconItemTintList(null);

Comment: Ya lo logre muchas gracias esque había puesto el atributo en el xml del navigationview por eso me aparecían de un solo color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que modificar tu NavigationView, está ubicada por defecto en el activity_main.xml, en esta vista debes agregar:

```
app:itemIconTint="@color/el_color_que_prefieras"
```

Y quedaría así

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/el_color_que_prefieras"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tal vez ya sepan la respuesta a esta pregunta, pero yo me acabo de enterar y queria compartir, lo unico que hay que hacer es añadir esta linea:

```
navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

En el `onCreate` de la `activity_main` y quedaran los iconos con los colores originales, saludos.

Comment: Si muchas gracias, esa forma fue la que empleé